# How to create a GString from a String?

Tags: rust, gtk, glib

I am using Rust with GLib and need to create a [`GString`](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.String.html). How do I do that?

```rust
fn example() -> GString {
    let hello = "Hello";
    // How do I return hello as a GString?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the documented function [`glib::GString::from_string_unchecked`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/latest/docs/glib/struct.GString.html#method.from_string_unchecked):

```rust
GString::from_string_unchecked("Hello".into())
```

Or use [`glib::gstr`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/latest/docs/glib/macro.gstr.html) to create a `&'static GStr` instead and turn it into something owned:

```rust
let hello = glib::gstr!("Hello");
hello.to_owned()
```